# How long is the prototype constructor chain?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype

I was going through Mozilla explanation of prototype inheritance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain. Thought of trying some exmple in chrome console.

```
function f() {
 this.a =1; 
 this.b =2;  
}
let o = new f();
f.prototype.b =3;
f.prototype.c =4;
```

I noticed that prototype of the function f() has a constructor and that again has a prototype and it keep going on like below:
f.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype.constructor

[image: Snap of the Chrome console. Trying to print prototype chain]

Now according to the mozilla documentation "Each object has a private property which holds a link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until an object is reached with null as its prototype. By definition, null has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain"

I am sure I am looking it from a wrong angle. Can someone put some perspective here. What actually is going on ? why do we have an unending constructor and prototype chain ?

Comment: Javascript Objects have a prototype which is in turn represented by Javascript Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular reference. Given a function, you can access the `prototype` property of it to get to the object that will be the *internal prototype* of any instances.

```js
function f() {
  this.a =1; 
  this.b =2;  
}
let o = new f();

console.log(f.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(o));
```

On this `.prototype` object, you can access its `constructor` property to get back to the associated function.

The `.prototype` of a function and `.constructor` of that prototype are links to each other. Given either, you can access the other.

The *actual* prototype chain for `f` is:

```
f <- Function.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

The prototype chain for `o` is:

```
o <- f.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

Note that the `.prototype` property does *not* reference the object that's the internal prototype of the one you're calling it on. To get to the internal prototype of some object `obj`, you have to use `Object.getPrototypeOf` (or `__proto__`, which is deprecated). The `.prototype` property is a special property of *functions* which will refer to the internal prototype of any instances of that function which may get created. Eg `const instance = new SomeClass()` will result in `instance` having an internal prototype of `SomeClass.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance Can you please provide some more details on internal prototype functionality ? Does this circular reference serve any purpose ? Why does Javascript have it in the first place ?

Comment: The internal prototype chain is something you can (and maybe have) read about in many tutorials - every object has an internal prototype of some other object or `null`, and usually, the top of the prototype chain is `Object.prototype`, though it's possible to create something that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` by using `Object.create`.

Comment: The circular reference is just for convenience - if all you have is the function, you can get to the internal prototype. But if all you have is the internal prototype, you can get to the function.

Comment: Thanks again @CertainPerformance. So the `console.log(f.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(o));`  is true cause every object inherits from Object. Am I correct there ?

Comment: Also can you also please explain why is `f.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(f)` results as false ?

Comment: (1) No, it's true because functions, when called with `new`, create objects whose internal prototype is the `.prototype` object of the function. The `.prototype` property (of functions) is somewhat misleadingly named, since it's easy to confuse one into thinking that it refers to *this object's* internal prototype - it'd be more accurately named `.internalPrototypeOfInstances`.

Comment: (2) Because the `.prototype` property refers to the internal prototype that *instances* of the function are set to, rather than the internal prototype of the *function itself*. (The internal prototype of the function is `Function.prototype`)